# Error when importing google play game services plugin to Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

When I import the Google Play Game Services Plugin for Unity into my project, the menu that should appear does not, and I get the following error in the console:

Assets/GooglePlayGames/Platforms/Native/NativeClient.cs(418,22): error CS1061: Type `Player' does not contain a definition for`PlayerId' and no extension method `PlayerId' of type`Player' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Assets/GooglePlayGames/Platforms/Native/NativeClient.cs(426,22): error CS1061: Type `Player' does not contain a definition for`DisplayName' and no extension method `DisplayName' of type`Player' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The guide on the github page for the plugin says that: After importing, you should see that two new menu items were added to the File menu: "Play Games Android setup" and "Play Games iOS setup". If you don't see the new menu items, refresh the assets by clicking Assets | Refresh and try again.

Unfortunately, however many times I refresh the assets, I do not see the menu items.

I am using Unity 4.6. How do I fix the error and get the google play game services plugin to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I had a script named Player. I did try renaming it, but I did not remember that unity does not properly rename the script - you have to do that in MonoDevelop!

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to solve.

First and simple:
Search in your scripts for someone what have named Player and change (file and definition of class)

```
class Player : MonoBehaviour { ...
```

to

```
class MyPlayer : MonoBehaviour { ...
```

Second and more complex. You need to find two files: **NativeClient.cs** and **NativePlayer.cs** . After you need to change some lines:

*NativePlayer.cs*
Add this line at top (line 28) : 
**using Player2 = GooglePlayGames.BasicApi.Multiplayer.Player;**

Line 58 change Player to Player2

*NativePlayer.cs*
Replace this function on line 45:

```
internal GooglePlayGames.BasicApi.Multiplayer.Player AsPlayer() {
    return new GooglePlayGames.BasicApi.Multiplayer.Player(Name(), Id());
}
```